# App Engine Development Environment - db.get() ReferenceProperty Query random error

Tags: google-app-engine

I have the following datastore model:

```
class FeatureCategory(db.Model):
    name_eng = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    name_spa = db.StringProperty()
    name_por = db.StringProperty()
    device_type = db.ReferenceProperty(DeviceType, required=True, collection_name='feature_categories')
```

```
class Feature(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    category = db.ReferenceProperty(FeatureCategory, required=True, collection_name='features')
    desc_eng = db.StringProperty()
    desc_spa = db.StringProperty()
    desc_por = db.StringProperty()
```

I've been experiencing errors when after doing a couple of db.get(db.Key('key_string')) and to the Referenced object like:

```
feats = dbmodel.Feature.all()
for feat in feats:
    cat = feat.category
```

in the development environment. If I stop the server and restart, it will work for some queries and be back to throwing the error below. Any ideas how can I fix this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Development/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2/webapp2.py", line 1536, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/Applications/Development/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2/webapp2.py", line 1530, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/Applications/Development/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/Applications/Development/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/Applications/Development/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/Applications/Development/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/danielgarcia/Documents/workspace/rfpbuilder/src/get.py", line 50, in get
    cat = feat.category
  File "/Applications/Development/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 3686, in __get__
    instance = get(reference_id)
  File "/Applications/Development/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 1536, in get
    return get_async(keys, **kwargs).get_result()
  File "/Applications/Development/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 592, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
  File "/Applications/Development/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1467, in __get_hook
    entities = rpc.user_data(entities)
  File "/Applications/Development/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/datastore.py", line 600, in local_extra_hook
    return extra_hook(result)
  File "/Applications/Development/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 1506, in extra_hook
    model = cls1.from_entity(entity)
  File "/Applications/Development/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 1441, in from_entity
    return cls(None, _from_entity=entity, **entity_values)
  File "/Applications/Development/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 973, in __init__
    prop.__set__(self, value)
  File "/Applications/Development/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 613, in __set__
    value = self.validate(value)
  File "/Applications/Development/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 2815, in validate
    value = super(StringProperty, self).validate(value)
  File "/Applications/Development/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 640, in validate
    raise BadValueError('Property %s is required' % self.name)
BadValueError: Property name is required
```

Comment: Please take the time to properly format your questions; they're extremely difficult to read if you won't.

Answer (score 3):

Please indent the code next time. The error message `Property name is required` indicates that some of your Feature entity don't have `name` property, which is marked as required in your model.

Comment: usually happens when an old version of your app writes to the datastore using the old model, and a newer version deployed reads the old data and fails.